# problems with deleting rows in big data sets in r

Tags: r

I wrote a script that delete rows that 20% of their cells ara smaller then 10.
it's work great on small data Sets but for big it's useless.
can sombody help me please.

here is my script:

```
     DataSets<-choose.files()

     DataSet<-read.delim(DataSets,header = TRUE,
     row.names = 1,sep="\t",blank.lines.skip=TRUE)

     delete<-0
     for(i in 1:length(DataSet[,1]))
      {
       count<-0
       for(j in 1:length(DataSet[i,]))
       {
         if(DataSet[i,j]<10 || is.na(DataSet[i,j]))
        {
           count=count+1
        }
       }
       if(count>0.2*length(DataSet[i,]))
       {
         DataSet=DataSet[-i,]
         delete<-delete+1
       } 
     }
```

Comment: So, based on the answers provided: do you include the number of `NA` values when determining whether 20% of the total row is less than 10, or just 20% of the numeric values?

Comment: R 101: for-loops are slow.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue Please don't encourage that myth! For loops are not inherently slow in R. It's the unnecessary copying by poorly written code _in_ the for loop that ends up being slow, and that is often avoidable (though not always, of course).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft just 20% of the numeric values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would solve your problem. You can leave your data as a DataFrame.

```
    dat<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100,10,1),10))
    bad<-apply(dat,1,function(x){
      return((sum(x<10,na.rm=TRUE)+sum(is.na(x)))>length(x)*0.2)
      })
    dat<-dat[!bad,]
```

Comment: this is unbelievable! i am grateful to you.

Comment: Good catch on counting the NAs. I missed that part of their code. (Note that `apply` will convert the data frame to a matrix anyway, so you're not really "avoiding" the matrix here.)

Comment: @ Jordan: Yes i am not realy avoiding it but only implicitly converting the data to a matrix. Is it faster if `dat` is a matrix instead of an data.frame?

Answer (score 5):

This is essentially instantaneous on my machine:

```
m <- matrix(runif(100000),10000,10)
system.time(m1 <- m[rowSums((m <= 0.25 | is.na(m)) < 2,])
```

I only approximated your exact situation, but your version would be analogous. The idea here would be to:

1. Use a matrix, rather than a data frame, if your data is indeed all numeric.
2. Use vectorized comparison to determine which elements are less than some value (0.25 in my example).
3. Then use `rowSums` to count how many values are less than 0.25 in each row.
4. Subset the matrix according to which rows have fewer than two values less than (or equal to) 0.25.

**Edit** Added check for NAs to count them too.

Answer (score 1):

This works pretty quickly for me.  Like the solution @joran used, I use a matrix:

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(1000, 15, 5), 100, 10)
tf <- apply(data, 1, function(x) x < 10) # your value of 10
data[-which(colSums(tf) > ncol(data)*0.2),] # here is where the 20% comes in
```

TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0, which is why one can use `colSums` here

#### Update to handle NAs

If one follows OP's comment to include "just 20% of the numeric values" and not the original code that counts `NA` values as values < 10, (i.e. delete rows where 20 % of numeric entries are less than 10), then this will work:

```
data[-which(colSums(tf, na.rm=T) > (ncol(data) - colSums(apply(tf,2,is.na)))*0.2),]
```

`colSums(apply(tf,2,is.na))` counts the number of entries in a row of `data` that are NA.

`(ncol(data) - colSums(apply(tf,2,is.na)))` subtracts that number from the number of columns so that only the total number of numeric columns is returned.

`(ncol(data) - colSums(apply(tf,2,is.na)))*0.2` is 20% of the number of numeric entries per row

Comment: This does not remove rows with more than 20% of `NA` values

Comment: @Floo0 Good point.  I hadn't seen how OP wanted to handle `NA` values.  OP said, "just 20% of the numeric values" in a comment, which could mean only to consider numeric entries when calculating what 20% is, which is different from your answer where you count the number of `NA` values as part of the values < 10 and calculate 20% as `0.2 * length of row`.  Does that make sense?  Perhaps I misinterpreted what OP wants?

Comment: Well whether it makes sense i dont know and this is definitely a point we could take about. It is just what he did in his loop:
`if(DataSet[i,j]<10 || is.na(DataSet[i,j])){count=count+1}`
I just copied the thought to be honest ;)